# Padding form into templateURL to be used with ngMessages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I'm new to angular and trying my hand at directives.

I would like to be able to use

```
<div ng-messages="form.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
</div>
```

Within a custom directive like so,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="s-input-{{name}}">
        {{text.human}}
        <span ng-if="text.subtext" class="form-hint">{{text.subtext}}</span>
    </label>

    <select ng-required="required" ng-model="model" class="form-control"  id="s-input-{{name}}" name="{{name}}" ng-options="t for t in text.select"></select>
    <div ng-messages="form.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can get it to work by passing using ng-messages below the directive element **but not in it.**

Although I really can't figure out how to pass the form in to the template so it can be accessed by ng-messages.

I've set up a plunker to show you my bare bones setup.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ELx6Fd2eLN4CJjEnzRGM?p=preview

I know I need to require the form with `require: '^form',` although I'm not sure how to use/access in the template URL.

I've been banging my head for a while so would really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you require the form directive with `require: '^form'` you then access that FormController in the `link` function. You can then simply attach that controller to the directive's scope like so:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, formController) {
    scope.form = formController;
}
```

Then reference it in the template:

```
<div ng-messages="form.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried that in the plunk but I couldn't get it to work, am I missing something? I have tried this method before. http://plnkr.co/edit/fvZXn0tDEc0a2IyOEnLy?p=preview

Comment: Your require is an array so you could use `scope.form = form[0]` or change the require to `require: '^form'` to make it work.

Comment: Aha that was it! I can't believe I was that silly thanks for you're help!

Answer (score 1):

You could always pass the form to your directive.

**javascript**

```
app.directive('selectGov', function (){ 
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'select.html',
        scope: {
            text: "=?",
            model: "=",
            required: "=",
            selectItems: "=?",
            name: "@?",
            form: "="
        },
    };
});
```

**html**

```
<select-gov model="person.phoneNumberType" text="q.phoneType" required="true" name="phoneType" form="myForm"></select-gov>
```

Comment: Yes I did try this, although due to having lots of these directives it seems a bit static/waste of code to have to keep adding the form to the directive.

Comment: But yes I agree that would be good but not for the situations I have in mind.

Comment: No, JC's answer is much better.